# How to load animate.css with Webpack 3?

Tags: webpack, animate.css, webpack-3

I'm trying to load animate.css to my app using following dependencies:

https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

https://github.com/andreimc/animate-css-webpack

I'd like to achieve that I'll be able to configure what animations will load using animate-css-web-pack.

Here's a list of all my dependencies in the project

```
"dependencies": {
  "animate-css-webpack": "^3.5.6",
  "animate.css": "^3.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.38",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.38",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
  "postcss": "^6.0.16",
  "postcss-loader": "^2.0.10",
  "stylus": "^0.54.5",
  "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
  "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
  "webpack": "^3.10.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
},
```

Relevant part of my webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
  'main': [
    'animate-css-webpack!./src/animate-css.config.js',
    './src/app.js',
  ]
},
```

However animate.css won't load… What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update:***

You don't need the `animate-css-webpack`-loader for this.

[image]

**Loading only a subset of animation effects manually** just do the following in your `main.css`:

```
@import "~animate.css/source/_base.css";
@import "~animate.css/source/attention_seekers/bounce.css";
@import ....
```

Now you have imported the `_base.css` which is the base for all other effects.
As you can see in the example above, I have only imported the `bounce` animation.
And then you can pull-in/remove effects as you wish, without having a separate config.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. I'm aware of this possibility. Perhaps I haven't worded my question right. What I really want is to have a webpack loader, so I can use a config file, that will enable me to switch on and off animations that I want to use in my project. For example, during the development period, I might want to include all animations, so I can try them out and see, how they improve the user experience. Once I'm ready for production, I'll simply switch off those I don't need and compile. That's what the advantage of using the animate-css-webpack should be.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The `animate-css-webpack` loader has not been updated a while now. I actually don't know why to use it, check the update.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: See update 2 for config usage. I used `webpack-modernizr-loader` here.

Comment: I'm using babel already, why would I want to use `modernizr` on top of that?

Comment: No worries, that happens to all of us. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can import `animate.css` using only one import statement, on JS or CSS side:

### Sass

```css
@import "~animate.css/source/animate.css";
```

### JavaSript/TypeScript

```js
import "animate.css/source/animate.css";
```

---

**Importing animate.css from the `source` folder is the only one necessary file to import** because it import all others files (_base.css, _vars.css and all effects):

```css
// source node_modules/animate.css/source/animate.css
@import '_vars.css';
@import '_base.css';

/* Attention seekers  */
@import 'attention_seekers/bounce.css';
@import 'attention_seekers/flash.css';
@import 'attention_seekers/pulse.css';
...
```

Comment: `@import "~animate.css/source/animate.css";` **did not** work. `@import "~animate.css/animate.css";` **did.**

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "~animate.css/source/_base.css";
```

imports the base css.